# Override default php session

Tags: ajax, php, session

I'm building a [AngularJs](http://angularjs.org) app using joomla in background. The AngularJs app get loaded once and then calls the server always through ajax. Some calls happen simultaneously. If I'm using the default PHP session in those calls, php will process one call at a time. So, I wrote my own Session handler to allow more than one call at a time and I would like use that in place of the default php Session. Is there a easy way to do this in Joomla or I will have to write my own JSession class?

**Edit**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    sleep(10);
    echo "Hello";
?>
```

If you call this file twice in the same browser in the same time, the first call will return in 10 seconds, the second call will return in 20 seconds. The JSession class call the session_start(), so the joomla has the same behavior.

**Edit**

When we use the database option or extend the JSessionStorage with own session handler, joomla use `session_set_save_handler()` and it changes the default behavior of lock the session. So, I was wrong when I say that to call session_start involves lock the session.

Comment: 1. Try to use database as session storage, and let me know if it solves the problem.
2. Number of simultaneous connection should be minimized.

Comment: A must read to understand behaviour of session and php - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430883/simultaneous-requests-to-php-script

Comment: Thanks @Shyam. I will read that and look at JSessionStorageDatabase class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to write your own JSession class, but you'll need to write a class extending `JSessionStorage` to integrate with Joomla's session handling.

Most likely you'll run into trouble when trying to set the the session handler trough the Global Configuration. Either override `JFormFieldSessionHandler` with a version that includes your handler or just specify it manually in `configuration.php`. However the latter option means that you might run into trouble when you try to use the Global Configuration in the future.

Comment: I will not have trouble in specify the session manually in configuration.php. I create my own admin interface in angular with a global configuration page. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This doesn't work. The php session is started in JSession class in the method _start. This method calls session_start that looks the session. I think that I need override the JSession class.

Comment: How does it lock the session when your Storage class does not support locking? I suppose at this point it would be easier if you could show some code.

Comment: have a look on my edit above

Comment: Have you tested this? If you don't enable locking in your driver than there will be no locking. Here's an example of a non-locking (non-Joomla) session storage: https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Session/Storage/Handler/MemcachedSessionHandler.php

Comment: Yes, I tested the code that I posted above. The class in your link only call the method of the memcached object. Where is the memcached code? What do you mean with "don't enable locking in your driver"? Do you talk about the native session of php? Is there a way to call session_start() and don't lock the php session?

Comment: The Memcached class is part of PHPs Memcached extension and written in C. As a comparison here's a Memcached session storage that does locking:https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle/blob/master/Session/Storage/LockingSessionHandler.php
Calling ``session_start()`` does not cause locking by itself. That's up to the storage solution.

Comment: Ok, it seams that memcache session doesn't lock the session. But it doesn't seam use the native php function `session_start()`. In a clean php installation with default configuration, calling `session_start()` will lock the session. I tested it, and JSession class call this native php function. Have a look in this http://www.php.net/function.session-start#101452

Comment: By default PHP will use the session handler configured in the php.ini. Most of these are locking, including the  default file handler. But Joomla overrides this using ``session_set_save_handler()``. This conversation is getting rather long, I'd encourage you to write a custom session handler and just test it. If you run into trouble consider opening a new question for the specific issue you encounter.

Comment: You are right. Using a custom session storage, even calling the `session_start()` the php don't look. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: It seams that the answer is not correct.

The default Joomla Session Handler (Database) does not lock the session while processing. So you don't have to worry about locking.

Anyway its possible that you override that session data of the first request with data of the second requests.

Comment: I'm going to look if the Database session handler meets my needs. Thanks

Comment: even using the Session Handler (Database), the JSession still starts the php session with session_start() call. It looks the session.

Comment: hmm, you are right, it seams that there is no way around this by standard php session handling. You can only close the session with session_write_close(); But I think you know this already...

Comment: Yes, The easiest way is copy the JSession and change it to call the session_start() and session_write_close() always it needs access $_SESSION.

Comment: Your answer is correct. See the Rouven Weßling answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the world of asynchronous calls. My advice is don't use sessions for the AJAX/RESTful calls at all. The most I would do is have some sort of authentication token so you know who is making the call.

Comment: Great advice. I'm going to think about that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Joomla allows you to create new Session Storage backends, which may solve your problem. Just extend `JSessionStorage` with your custom session class, and then you can set the handler in your configuration.php file directly. (Custom session storage backends don't show up in the global admin config.)